# Почему не применяются css стили?

Tags: css, wordpress

Проблема началась вчера, зашел на сайт а там такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

css находит, но не применяет. Просил у друзей проверить работоспособность, и все было хорошо.

Подскажите что я делаю не так?

Comment: Что вы уже пытались сделать для исправления ошибки? Если переименовать файл стиля и указать на него новую ссылку, ошибка сохраняется?

Comment: пробовал переименовать, сделать бекап, менял атрибут в админке, ничего не помогло. У всех вроде работает, но у меня нет.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в ваш вопрос больше информации: проблемный код, сообщения об ошибках (если есть), описания сервера, его настройки и т. д. Это заметно повысит шансы получения правильного ответа.

Comment: использую бесплатный хостинг https://beget.ru/, в настройках не разбираюсь, поэтому ничего не менял. Ошибок никаких не выдает. Последнее что сделал это добавил <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">, а потом все сломалось

Comment: Зашел на ваш сайт. По-моему, у вас где-то в коде не большая ошибка, и из-за этого не хочет работать. Перепроверьте код

Comment: @ВиталяДьяков если не работает только у вас, то возможно проблема и не в сайте вовсе

Comment: у меня отоброжается только в сафари под виндоус

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо всем кто пытался помочь, в действительности ошибка была минимальная

- @font-face{      font-family: 'FiveMinutes';     src:
  url('five_minutes-webfont.eot');     src:
  url('five_minutes-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('five_minutes-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('five_minutes-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),

> url('five_minutes-webfont.svg#five_minutes-webfont) format('svg');

эта строка принесла мне много бед

Answer (score 0):

На некоторых ресурсах предлагают заменить ваш линк на один из двух, причем абсолютно не меняя

> Here you need to put full path(url) of the css file.You can add
>   style.css in header.php file two ways:
>
> You can include stylesheet as per wordpress format:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php
> bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
```

> OR
>
> You can include manually style.css file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php
> bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/style.css" />
```

Comment: ну я не понимаю, что мне надо делать в таком случае?

Comment: просто добавить одну из этих линков, вместо того что у вас есть

Comment: это не помогло, отображается хорошо только на телефоне ((